# services and key events

Tags: android, android-intent

In need a keylistener when my application is running in background. Knowing that KeyEvents can only be handled by Activities, what would be the best way around?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not possible in general, for obvious privacy and security reasons. You have no rights to find out what the user types in unless you are the foreground activity.

A few buttons will send out broadcasts if their events are not consumed by the foreground activity, such as the CAMERA button.

Comment: Yes it is logical even though our application won't be available on the Android Market. When the user launch the application, he enters a certain number of parameters and then go back to the homescreen. How could I interact from there to use a keyEvent?

Comment: @MademoiselleLenore: Download the source code to Android, modify the operating system to suit, package it into a modded ROM, and install that ROM on devices.